# Unable to access WPadmin, website down

Tags: plugins, fatal-error, mu-plugins

**I'm not a dev. This is little too much for me. Can anybody just point me in the direction as to what the hell is going on??**
Tried to recover a good working point. Tried disabling Plugins. Increased memory. MediaTemple washed their hands of me. Help!

> Deprecated: base64_decode(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /var/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/gd-system-plugin/plugins/worker/src/MWP/Worker/Request.php on line 198
>
> Deprecated: Return type of Wpsec\twofa\Services\container\Container::offsetExists($id) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset):
>
> Deprecated: Constant FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated in /var/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/gd-system-plugin/includes/class-debug-mode.php on line 113
>
> Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset):
>
> Deprecated: Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset):
>
> Deprecated: Constant FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated in /var/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/gd-system-plugin/includes/class-debug-mode.php
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: round(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given in /var/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/force-strong-passwords/slt-force-strong-passwords.php:53
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/force-strong-passwords/slt-force-strong-passwords.php(53): round('6.0.3', 1)
> #1 /var/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/slt-force-strong-passwords.php(14): require('/var/www/wp-con...')
> #2 /var/www/wp-settings.php(353): include_once('/var/www/wp-con...')
> #3 /var/www/wp-config.php(110): require_once('/var/www/wp-set...')
> #4 /var/www/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/var/www/wp-con...')
> #5 /var/www/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/var/www/wp-loa...')
> #6 /var/www/index.php(17): require('/var/www/wp-blo...')
> #7 {main} thrown in /var/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/force-strong-passwords/slt-force-strong-passwords.php on line 53`

Comment: So it looks like you're running PHP 8.1 and the Force Strong Passwords plugin - which is abandoned - is not PHP 8.1 compatible. You should [fix it](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-php-8-1-compatible-critical-error-with-php-8-1/) or remove it. You cannot disable as it's in `mu-plugins`, which means Must Use Plugins.

Comment: Start by [disabling your plugins](https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005593985-Disable-WordPress-plugins-in-phpMyAdmin) directly in the database. Then look into replacements or updated versions of problem plugins.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot disable mu-plugins in the manner that @t31os describes.

Comment: Move them out of the mu-plugins directory in that case, i did miss that detail.

Comment: Also, WordPress is not fully compatible with PHP 8.1, so I recommend sticking with PHP 8.0 meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

go to the WordPress directory wp-content/plugin/ and rename the folder "force-strong-passwords" to force-strong-passwords-d

If it worked then it is a plugin error
remove this plugin and install its alternative plugin

If you still need this plugin than contact to the plugin author

Comment: From the stack trace it's actually in mu-plugins, and a rename there won't work it'll still get loaded.